# NPM Install 404 Resource

Tags: node.js, gulp-sass, node-sass

after this command:

```
npm install node-sass
```

it throws this error:

> Cannot download
>   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

I'm using the Node.js command prompt, I did `npm update` 5 times, it still tries to download from a 404 repo... i found the working repo requested node but I can't find how to download it manually and start the installation from there, thanks for Your help, I'm using Windows x64.

Comment: You are using NodeJS command prompt? Sorry, didn't get this line. Do you mean, you open console and then run node command to enter reply and then tried nom install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As their [documentation](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#404s) says:

> If you see a 404 when trying to install node-sass, this indicates that your trying to install a version of node-sass that doesn't support your version of NodeJS, or uses an alternate V8 environment (Meteor, Electron, etc...) that isn't supported by node-sass.
>
> If you encounter this, please check what version of NodeJs you're running (node -v) and check for a supported version of node-sass for your NodeJs by checking our [release](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases) page.